# Mutation testing: does anybody know mutant?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec, mutation-testing

Yesterday  a stumble in this [article](http://solnic.eu/2013/01/23/mutation-testing-with-mutant.html) on Mutation Testing and immediatly had a try with  [elasticrepo](https://github.com/lgs/elasticrepo) a lib I'm writing to index github on elasticsearch.

Unfurtunatly it seems I'm missing something, because I don't get any so called "Killed: rspec" and zero mutations:

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/elasticrepo$ mutant -I lib/elasticrepo -r repo_subset --rspec-dm2 ::RepoSubset
Mutant configuration:
Matcher:   #<Mutant::Matcher::ObjectSpace scope_name_pattern=/\ARepoSubset(\z|::)/>
Filter:    Mutant::Mutation::Filter::ALL
Strategy:  #<Mutant::Strategy::Rspec::DM2>

subjects:   0
mutations:  0
noop_fails: 0
kills:      0
alive:      0
mtime:      0.00s
rtime:      0.01s
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/elasticrepo$
```

now I think it could be related to the path and  then here they are in this case :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/elasticrepo$ ls -l lib/elasticrepo
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  333 Jun  8 16:07 extractor.rb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave 1960 Jun  8 16:07 indexer.rb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave 1330 Jun  8 16:07 repo_subset.rb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave   43 Jun  1 12:28 version.rb
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/elasticrepo$
```

and here it is the "structure" of the class to test ( in terms of namespace ):

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/elasticrepo$ head -2 lib/elasticrepo/repo_subset.rb
module Elasticrepo
  class RepoSubset
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/elasticrepo$
```

Please feel free to se the entire code to test for mutation: [elasticrepo](https://github.com/lgs/elasticrepo)

It's also possible something goes wrong with regex because of the responce line :

```
Matcher:   #<Mutant::Matcher::ObjectSpace scope_name_pattern=/\ARepoSubset(\z|::)/>
```

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: Author of mutant here.

Just cloned your repo. Changes needed:

- Mutant currently only runs under mri-1.9.3 and rbx 19-mode. I'll port it to 2.0.0 soon.
- Specify the fully qualified constant name, `::Elasticrepo::RepoSubset` instead of `::RepoSubset`
- Also note that for current mutant releases the flag `--rspec-dm2` was replaced with simply `--use rspec`

Mutant does run correctly with this changes.

Happy mutating!

Comment: 2.0.0 support is in the latest beta releases of the 0.3 series.

Comment: Just for your info. The 0.3 series was released with nice 2.0 support. I'm currently working on 0.4 that features more flexibility in test selection and fixes some other issues.